# Do I need to be 'current' or hold a medical to become a Basic Ground Instructor?

Tags: faa-regulations, ground-instructor

I want to become an aviation ground instructor BGI.
I hold a commercial, multi, instrument and F/E pilot certificate but haven’t flown in a long time.

1. Do I need to be “ current” to become a BGI?
2. Do I need an FAA medical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need a medical certificate.  It also does not matter that you have not flown in a long time.  You will need to study and take two separate tests to get you ground instructor certificate.

- Fundamentals of Instruction (FOI) Test
- Ground Instructor Test

The FOI information is covered extensively in the Aviation Instructor Handbook and is 50 questions (at least it once was).

The Flight Instructor test question bank is also used for the BGI (Basic Ground Instructor) and AGI (Advanced Ground Instructor) tests.  If I remember correctly, the BGI test is 80 questions and the AGI test is 100 questions.  The information on the test is covered in multiple FAA handbooks (not all inclusive):

- Pilots Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge
- Airplane Flying Handbook
- Rotorcraft Flying Handbook
- Balloon Flying Handbook
- Aviation Weather Services

One thing to notice is that the ground instructor test covers all aircraft and not just the "airplane category" as you can teach and sign off written tests for all aircraft.  Since the BGI and the AGI are the same test, I would suggest getting an AGI as you will be able to sign off all written tests and not just tests for sport, recreational or private pilots.

Comment: Your answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to check out FAR Title 14, Chapter 1, Subchapter D, Part 61, Subpart 1, §61.215-§61.217.

To be eligible for a ground instructor certificate you must:

(1) Be at least 18

(2) Be able to read, write, speak, and understand English

(3) Pass a knowledge test on instruction (not necessary if you are already a CFI, hold a 7th grade or higher teaching certificate, or work as an accredited teacher at a college or university.

(4) Pass a knowledge test on aeronautical knowledge.

Once you have the rating, to act as a basic ground instructor, one of these things must occur during the preceding 12 calendar months to be considered “current”:

(a) Employment or activity as a ground instructor giving pilot, flight instructor, or ground instructor training

(b) Employment or activity as a flight instructor giving pilot, flight instructor, or ground instructor ground or flight training

(c) Completion of an approved flight instructor refresher course and receipt of a graduation certificate for that course

(d) Receive an endorsement from an authorized instructor certifying that the person has demonstrated knowledge in the appropriate subject areas.

No medical is required.